# Problems with php shell_exec permissions

Tags: php, linux, apache2

I'm running as `www-data` and I'm trying to execute a shell script using `shell_exec(/foobar/script/myscript.sh)`, but I'm getting the following error when the script attempts to write to a log file

```
cannot create /foobar/foo.log: Permission denied
```

However, I don't run into any problems if I try running the script directly from the terminal. ie

```
$ sudo su www-data
$ /foobar/script/myscript.sh
$
```

Any idea what could be going on here?

I should also add that I added www-data to the group mybar and that this is what's showing up when I list the directory

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 mybar mybar  4096 May 14 14:18 foobar     # ls -l /


-rw-rw-r-- 1 mybar mybar 2824 May 15 09:57 foo.log     # ls -l /foobar
```

Comment: Could you inspect `whoami` after `sudo su www-data`? Usually it has no login shell, and you fall right back to `root`... Which would explain things, because unless `www-data` is in the `mybar` group it cannot write there.

Answer (score 1):

I think there can be two options:

1. web-server and php-fpm are run under different users (by default that should not be). Try echo shell_exec('whoami');
2. You have added www-data to mybar after php-fpm process had been started so it still "doesn't know" that it is (then I think restart of fpm should help).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R foobar/
```

The directory you are trying to create the file in must belong to whoever is executing the command.

You can type:

```
ls -la
```

to see who it belongs to.

You should see something like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 jack jack  4096 Jul 22 11:36 application
```

When I am logged into my ubuntu machine I am logged in as `jack@jack` so I can create files in the following directory without issuing the `sudo` command:

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 jack jack  4096 Jul 22 11:36 application
```

because it is owned by the current user.

When you try running a script that is executed by visiting a webpage. `www-data` is the user that is executing the command so any directory or file that you are trying to create/modify/delete must be owned by `www-data`.